# Mocking function with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I am running into an issue with mocking function calls with Jest. This is the line that I need to be mocked:

```
let res = await bot.getUser(userId);
```

The bot object is accessed through a module and makes an API call to fetch the user object.

Things that I have tried:

1. I replaced that line with  `let userInfo = await getUser(userId, bot);` and moved the logic above into that file. This is what that file looks like:

```
export const getUser = async (userId, bot) => {
    let res = await bot.getUser(userId);

    return res;
};
```

2. I followed the Jest docks and created a `__mocks__` folder and added `getUser.js`
3. `/__mocks__/getUser.js` looks like this:

```
export const getUser = () => {
    return Promise.resolve({
        user: { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' },
    });
};
```

My test (the `getUser` call is inside `handleMessage4Bot`):

```
import { handleMessage4Bot } from '../src/handlers/index';

jest.mock('../src/utils/getUser');

const event = { type: 'Message4Bot' };
it('Should return John Doe', async () => {
    let response = await handleMessage4Bot(event);
    expect(response).toBe({
        user: { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' },
    });
});
```

[image: Error]

When I test only `getUser` it still returns `undefined`:

```
import getUser from '../getUser';

jest.mock('../getUser');

it('Should return John Doe', async () => {
    let response = await getUser();
    console.log('response :>> ', response);

    expect(response).toStrictEqual({
        user: { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' },
    });
});
```

[image: Error 2]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working for me, using the code you provided.  I think your directory structure or where you are defining things could be messed up.  For example, I noticed that you are importing `getUser` from `../src/utils/index;` but your mock is in `../src/utils/getUser`

My working example:

src/utils/getUser.js

```
module.exports = async () => {
  return Promise.resolve({
    user: { firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe' },
  });
};
```

scr/utils/__tests__/getUserTest.js

```
const getUser = require('../getUser');

jest.mock('../getUser');

it('Should return John Doe', async () => {
  let response = await getUser();
  console.log('response :>> ', response);
  expect(response).toStrictEqual({
    user: { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' },
  });
});
```

src/utils/__mocks__/getUser.js

```
module.exports = async () => {
  return Promise.resolve({
    user: { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' },
  });
};
```

Comment: I think you might be right, I am adjusting the file structure now. I think your `src/utils/getUser.js` is incorrect though, is that a typo?

Comment: I added the contents of `src/utils/getUser.js` to the main question

Comment: I don't have the bot or anything setup, so my src/utils/getUser was just a dummy - note that it returns the static "Jane Doe" instead of "John Doe"

Comment: Hmm I'm reading your post, and it still looks (from the final test case) like you are using index: `import { getUser } from '../src/utils/index';`

Comment: I created a separate project and your tests do work. It looks like my issue has to do with Babel configurations with Jest. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my problem was my Jest and Babel configurations. I fixed the issues by running:

```
yarn add --dev babel-jest @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

then

`npx jest --init` or (if jest is installed globally) `jest --init`
Then followed the instructions and selected `babel`.